# Can I render a dynamic layout on Android that is received via API?

Tags: android, html, android-layout

I have a use case where given a URL like `example.com/code/abcd12` on my web server, I want to display its contents in my Android app. The contents usually include forms, buttons, text and  pictures.

Right now, I'm using a webview to do that. But I was wondering if it made it made more sense for my API to return a Android XML layout. (Lets assume we can handle converting HTML elements to Android elements on the server side).

- Can such a layout file be loaded using `setContentView(R.layout.layout_from_api);`
- Is it worth the effort? Can parsing and loading a native layout be faster that a webview rendering HTML and applying CSS classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically you can. And i also had a project in which the admin changes the application forms in the server and the the forms gets updated in the client devices,To accomplish this what you want to do is

1.Agree upon which widgets are to be supported in the design,

2.Use a format that is easy to transfer the xml properties to the client

3.Write a parser that can parse the layout design response from the server and inflate it to a view.

After doing all these you can  use the `setContentView()` in the code.

Comment: @Felipe points out that I cannot use setContentView() as the layout is available on compile time. How did you do it then. I assume it's not as straightforward as parsing the text as xml and passing it as a param.

Comment: Actually you can use setContentView() in this case, but you can't, for example, access the elements using findViewById(). You'll need to create references to the widgets while rendering them.

Comment: Exactly,i did it just by creating objects for all the widgets and adding them while parsing the response

Comment: Cool. Will try it out. Cheers to both of you :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can such a layout file be loaded using
>   setContentView(R.layout.layout_from_api);

No, it is not possible... the xml layout shall be parsed in the compile time (when the references in R class will be created)

> Is it worth the effort? Can parsing and loading a native layout be
>   faster that a webview rendering HTML and applying CSS classes?

I think it is a good idea, because the user experience will be better - the user is always more comfortable with the native widgets.

But your implementation will not be simple: you need to create a parser which will take the XML file and will render the widgets described there programmaticaly. It is not impossible, think about it.